# C# Ninject: How to bind to method async

Tags: c#, async-await, ninject

I am using Ninject 3.2.2.0 and I am trying to bind an async method.

This is what I got so far:

```
kernel.Bind<Task<MyInterface>>().ToMethod(async ctx =>
{
   var someData = await DoSomethingAsync();
   return new SomethingElse(someData);
}).InRequestScope();
```

My method `DoSomethingAsync` never gets called. I believe it's not being called because `MyInterface` is being requested, not `Task<MyInterface>`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction of your object graph should be [reliable and fast](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). This excludes doing anything that is I/O related. This means that you should *not* do anything that is asynchronous **at all**.

Instead anything that is slow, unreliable or asynchronous should be postponed untill *after* the object graph is constructed.

Comment: Say there is meta data on a CurrentUser object that needs to be requested from a service or database or both. And say you have 5 domain objects to construct that depend on CurrentUser. Are you going to request that data 5 times per request? Why not bind Task<CurrentUser> to a method that can return it? Just because it returns a task doesn't mean the IOC needs to await it. The domain objects that require Task<CurrentUser> can await it. The difference is the data is only requested once. The dependencies all await the same task.

Comment: @StewartAnderson: I've got the feeling that you're asking a new question here. If you post it as such here on SO and provide appropriate details (some sample code would be helpful) and post a link to that question here in the comments, I will do my best to answer that question.

Comment: To say that your IOC should have nothing asnyc in it would have prevented my solution to the problem.

To generalize my solution down to one line of IOC binding code:

kernel.Bind<Task<CurrentUser>>().ToMethod(c => UserProvider.Get()).InRequestScope();

Anything that needs current user now receives it asynchronously via IOC. Objects constructed by IOC that require Task<CurrentUser> await the task but those objects all await the same task because of the .InRequestScope().

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making my binding sync

```
kernel.Bind<MyInterface>().ToMethod(ctx =>
{
   var someData = DoSomethingSync(); // <-- Made this one sync, see method below
   return new SomethingElse(someData);
}).InRequestScope();
```

Here is the 'magic'. I changed my method from:

```
private async Task<string> DoSomethingAsync() {
  var result = await DoSomethingElseAsync();
  return result;
}
```

To

```
private string DoSomethingSync() {
   string result = null;

   var runSync = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
      result = await DoSomethingElseAsync();
   }).Unwrap();
   runSync.Wait();

   return result;
}
```

I know performance is affected because of the context switch, but at least it works as expected and you can be sure that it won't deadlock.